# How to download and save file from Google Cloud Storage on android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I am trying out google cloud storage; here is my code:

```
File file = new File("mydir" + "/" + fileName);
Storage.Objects.Get get = storage.objects().get("bucketname", fileName);
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

get.executeAndDownloadTo(stream);
stream.flush();
stream.close();
```

The download is working (*am not getting any error or crush*) I checked that by setting break point and inspecting the `file` object. I checked `file.exists()` which returns `true` and `file.length()` which returns `847` byes.

But if I go to my phone and try to access the file I cant find it; also the file I am downloading is a picture file if I try to create a bitmap out of it I always get null.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath())
```

Comment: I can see the file using root file explorer and it seems `get.executeAndDownloadTo(stream);` is not fully downloading the file. The actual file size is 7KB but am getting only 847.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution; so the issue is with this code:

```
get.executeAndDownloadTo(stream)
```

is not downloading the file fully for a reason that I dont know.

Solution: I wrote a simple util method that copies the input stream to output stream byte by byte:

```
public static void copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
    final int buffer_size = 4096;

    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];

    for (int count=0;count!=-1;) {
        count = is.read(bytes);
        if(count != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);               
        }
    }

    os.flush();
    is.close();
    os.close();

}
```

Call:

```
Utils.copyStream(get.executeMediaAsInputStream(), stream);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution! That seems lousy. I suspect you might have more luck with the newer google-cloud Java library: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java

Comment: Thanks but at the bottom of the page it says "Android is currently unsupported." :)